# How to load html.DropdownList to the table <td> from Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc-4

In my asp.net MVC application, Im trying to create a purchase order view with item adding button.

So for the first **<-td> tag** I want to show the dropdown list and other columns with input text fields.

Then the Rows are added to the table using javascript.

Want to know how to add same input with the current styles (td width and class) from the javascript.

This is my current code

HTML

```
<tbody class="table-border-bottom-0">
   <tr id="tablerow0">
     <td>
       <strong> 1</strong>
     </td>
     <td width="40%"> @Html.DropDownList("Item_ID", null, "--Select the Item--", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-select", @Id = "Company", oninvalid = "this.setCustomValidity('Select the Item')", oninput = "this.setCustomValidity('')", name = "Item_Id[0]" }) @* <input name="Item_Id[0]" type="text" value="" required="required" class="form-control" />*@ </td>
     <td width="10%">
       <input name="AdditionalComments[0]" type="text" value="" required="required" class="form-control" />
     </td>
     <td width="10%">
       <input name="AcidStables[0]" type="text" value="" class="form-control" />
     </td>
     <td width="20%">
       <input name="AcidStables[0]" type="text" value="" class="form-control" />
     </td>
     <td width="20%">
       <input name="AcidStables[0]" type="text" value="" class="form-control" />
     </td>
     <td>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="removeTr(0);">x</button>
     </td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>

<p>
   <button id="add" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
</p>
```

Javascript

```
var counter = 2;
$(function () {
  $('#add').click(function () {
    $('<tr id="tablerow' + counter + '"> ' +
      '<td >' +
      '<label id="CountItems" > <strong>' + counter + '</strong> </label> </td>' +
      '<td width="40%">' +
      '<input type="text" class="text-box single-line"  name="Item_Id[' + counter + ']" value="" required="required"  />' +
      '</td>' +

      '<td width="10%">' +
      '<input type="text" class="text-box single-line"  name="AcidStables[' + counter + ']" value="" required="required" />' +
      '</td>' +
      '<td width="10%">' +
      '<input type="text" class="text-box single-line"  name="AcidStables[' + counter + ']" value="" required="required" />' +
      '</td>' +
      '<td width="20%">' +
      '<input type="text" class="text-box single-line"  name="AcidStables[' + counter + ']" value="" required="required" />' +
      '</td>' +
      '<td width="20%">' +
      '<input type="text" class="text-box single-line"  name="AcidStables[' + counter + ']" value="" required="required" />' +
      '</td>' +
      '<td>' +
      '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="removeTr(' + counter + ');">x</button>' +
      '</td>' +
      '</tr>').appendTo('#submissionTable');
    counter++;
    return false;
  });
});

function removeTr(index) {
  if (counter > 1) {
    $('#tablerow' + index).remove();
    counter--;
  }
  return false;
}
```

This is how the current view looks

Before clicking on the **Add Button**

[image]

After clicking to the **Add Button**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the modified JavaScript code:

```
 var counter = 2;
    var dropdownOptions = [
      {
        value: "option1",
        text: "Option 1",
      },
      {
        value: "option2",
        text: "Option 2",
      },
      {
        value: "option3",
        text: "Option 3",
      },
    ];
    
    $(function () {
      $("#add").click(function () {
        var newRow = $(
          '<tr id="tablerow' +
            counter +
            '"> ' +
            "<td>" +
            '<label id="CountItems"><strong>' +
            counter +
            "</strong></label>" +
            "</td>" +
            '<td width="40%">' +
            '<select class="form-select" name="Item_Id[' +
            counter +
            ']" required="required">' +
            "</select>" +
            "</td>" +
            '<td width="10%">' +
            '<input type="text" class="text-box single-line" name="AdditionalComments[' +
            counter +
            ']" value="" required="required" />' +
            "</td>" +
            '<td width="10%">' +
            '<input type="text" class="text-box single-line" name="AcidStables[' +
            counter +
            ']" value="" required="required" />' +
            "</td>" +
            '<td width="20%">' +
            '<input type="text" class="text-box single-line" name="AcidStables[' +
            counter +
            ']" value="" required="required" />' +
            "</td>" +
            '<td width="20%">' +
            '<input type="text" class="text-box single-line" name="AcidStables[' +
            counter +
            ']" value="" required="required" />' +
            "</td>" +
            "<td>" +
            '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="removeTr(' +
            counter +
            ');">x</button>' +
            "</td>" +
            "</tr>"
        );
    
        var selectElement = newRow.find("select"); // Find the <select> element in the new row
    
        // Populate the <select> element with options
        dropdownOptions.forEach(function (option) {
          var optionElement = $("<option>").val(option.value).text(option.text);
          selectElement.append(optionElement);
        });
    
        newRow.appendTo("#submissionTable");
        counter++;
        return false;
      });
    });
    
    function removeTr(index) {
      if (counter > 1) {
        $("#tablerow" + index).remove();
        counter--;
      }
      return false;
    }
```

Hope Its Work !!

Comment: Of course it worked !! Thank you so much for the answer. And May I ask you another small favor to the same question, For the Dropdown, I'm populating the items from the ``viewbag`` . Could you show me , how to get viewbag data to the ``dropdownOptions`` options ? My controller code is ``ViewBag.Item_ID = new SelectList(db.Items.Where(x => x.Status == true && x.CompanyID == CompanyId), "ID", "ItemName_Number");``

Comment: var dropdownOptions = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(ViewBag.Options)); // Importing options from ViewBag.                  Can you try this?

Comment: error in the ``Serialize`` . ''Json not containing the definition of Serizalize'' Error occurred

Comment: I changed it to the ``@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.Item_ID));`` this, And When Debug the code , I saw the data coming to the ``var dropdownoptions`` but it wouldn't load the data to the combo box

Comment: Finally find out and it worked. Thanks for the help.